# How to create a caching layer on top of slick that could be applied globally?

Tags: scala, slick

I am curios if using scala and slick, you could create a flexible caching layer (say using memcached) on top of slick.

Ruby has a cool library called IdentityCache: https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache

It allows you to simply extend your model class (a trait in scala?) where you tell it to use this cache layer.

You can then tell it to only cache by Id, or cache associations also etc.

Sounds like a very cool thing, how could something like this fit into slick's design?

Comment: How is cache invalidation handled in identity_cache? How do you know when you can read from cache or when it is outdated?

Comment: E.g. if I add a new image for a product in my db, does a cached product contain it, when using `cache_has_many :images` or not?

Comment: @cvogt In their doc it says `IdentityCache keeps track of the objects that have cached indexes and uses an after_commit hook to expire those objects, and any up the tree, when they are changed.`  So when something is saved an event fires that expires the cache.  I'll have to research how it invalidates when child associations are updated.

Comment: Well I guess that explanation does explain it, it knows that it is a child association so goes up the tree since the associations are defined and known at runtime.

Comment: Ok, if you only supports lookups and joins by equality (not comparison or inequality for example) and no aggregations, etc., then this may just work.

Comment: @cvogt I'm looking at the source of slick, where exactly do the classes generate the raw sql sent to mysql?

Comment: The query is compiled to SQL at the moment the query is implicitly converted to an invoker or executor using these implicits: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/profile/BasicProfile.scala#L46

Comment: The compiler goes through several phases. Eventually, the SQL code generation happens here in the driver https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/driver/MySQLDriver.scala and here https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/driver/JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala

Comment: +1 I'd like to see cache in Slick

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about how to add this to Slick lately, but we don't have any resources assigned to it for the foreseeable future.

You could build a query cache on top of Slick. Invalidating the cache based on the observed write operations on the base data can be very hard for arbitrary queries. You would need to restrict the supported operations for conditions in cached queries, e.g. to only use equality. Oracle and others have similar restrictions in place for their materialized view maintenance features.

Comment: Hi @cvogt, can you tell if this feature has been introduced lately in Slick?